# Rotating region defined by $y=4x-x^2 \; and \; y=0$ around y-axis, find the volume.

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, solid-of-revolution

I need to rotate that region around the y-axis. I'm assuming this means I will have to use the shell method. Finding the intersection gives me $x=0 \; and \; x = 4$ So is this how I should set up the problem?

$$V= \int_0^4 2\pi(x)(4x-x^2-0)dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: You have the correct set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: Not to reiterate what you've done,... but for this example, we use the Shell method: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^4 2\pi\cdot x\cdot (4x-x^2)dx$ . Can you continue ? Note that in the "calculus book", they said $f(x) = 4x-x^2$ was the "height" of the "cylinder" and the base is a circular shell whose area is $2\pi xdx$.

Comment: Great, so I was correct. Just a sec, let me see if I can get this.

Comment: Ok, here is my final volume, $128\pi \over3$. I took your advice from my last question and went and looked up the shell, washer, and disk methods. Does my answer look correct? Thank you!

Comment: that seems ok to me, did you check the right answer in the student solution manual of "the book" ?

Comment: the only reason I'm asking these questions is that they come from the even questions in my book. There are no solutions for the even questions, and they are usually a little bit harder it seems. Thanks again.